# Calling functions from other functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with making this program work all it returns after the inputs is `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3



def displaymenu():

    input32=int(input("1)  Run experiment\n2) Exit"))
    return input32  
def cal1(we,woc,wa):

    wala=we*woc(wa-woc)
    return wala

def cal2(wo,woh):

    wolo=24*wo*woh*wa
    return wolo

def cal3(wa,woc):

    wele=wa**2+woc(wa-woc)
    return wele

def beamere(wala,wolo,wele):

    y=(wala/wolo)*wele
    return y

input32 = displaymenu()
while input32 is not 2:

    if input32 == 1:
        we= int(input("enter your width"))
        wo= int(input("enter what ever this is"))
        woh=int(input("enter this thing"))
        wa= int(input("i really should stop calling my varibles random sylibles"))
        woc=int(input("enter your woc"))
        wala  =  cal1(we,woc,wa)
        wolo  =  cal2(wo,woh)
        wele  =  cal3(wa,woc)
        y     =  beamere(wala,wolo,wele)
        print(y)



    elif input32 == 2:


        print("learn english")
        break
    else:
        input32 = displaymenu()
```

Comment: `woc(wa-woc)` is a function call, not multiplication. And yes, you shouldn't use such terrible variable names, but maybe fix that instead of including it in the prompt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in the function  **def cal1** modify the line
from

```
wele=wa**2+woc(wa-woc)
```

to

```
wele=wa**2+woc*(wa-woc)
```

## woc(wa-woc)-> indicates a function call for woc with argument 'wa-woc'

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your `cal1` and `cal3`:
When doing `wala=we*woc(wa-woc)` you are telling python to use `woc` as a function where you were probably meaning to use `wala=we*woc*(wa-woc)` to multiply `woc` by `(wa-woc)`. The same goes with the second function.

Here is how your functions would look :

```
def cal1(we,woc,wa):

    wala=we*woc(wa-woc)
    return wala

def cal3(wa,woc):

    wele=wa**2+woc(wa-woc)
    return wele
```